# c# Microsoft SyncFramework - update filename

Tags: c#, microsoft-sync-framework

I use the Microsoft SyncFramework for Filesyncronization in C# .NET

The Synchronisation works well but when I update a filename in the source, there will be a new created in the Destination path. Also when I Change a file in the Destination, it won't be updated from the source path or if I delete a file in the source path, it doens't delete the file in the Destination.

Does anybody can help me?

Here is my Code:

```
var sourceId = new SyncId(Guid.NewGuid());
var destId = new SyncId(Guid.NewGuid());

FileSyncOptions options = FileSyncOptions.ExplicitDetectChanges 
            | FileSyncOptions.RecycleDeletedFiles 
            | FileSyncOptions.RecyclePreviousFileOnUpdates 
            | FileSyncOptions.RecycleConflictLoserFiles;

FileSyncScopeFilter filter = new FileSyncScopeFilter();
filter.FileNameExcludes.Add("*.metadata");

var sourceProvider = new FileSyncProvider(
            sourceId.GetGuidId(), _sourcePath, filter, options);
var destinationProvider = new FileSyncProvider(
            destId.GetGuidId(), _destinationPath, filter, options);

sourceProvider.Configuration.ConflictResolutionPolicy = 
            ConflictResolutionPolicy.SourceWins;
destinationProvider.Configuration.ConflictResolutionPolicy = 
            ConflictResolutionPolicy.SourceWins;

sourceProvider.DetectChanges();
destinationProvider.DetectChanges();

var agent = new SyncOrchestrator();
agent.LocalProvider = sourceProvider;
agent.RemoteProvider = destinationProvider;

agent.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.Upload;
agent.Synchronize();
```

Comment: can you log what conflicts/errors are raised?

Comment: There are no Errors or conflicts  it simply doensn't sync correctly...